# Migrating Identity in .net core 2 class library

Tags: asp.net-identity, class-library, asp.net-core-2.0

I've been trying to add a class library with Identity to a .net core 2 project.

### Project `Startup.cs`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<MyDbContext, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
   }
```

Class library:

```
namespace MSContext
{
    public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
    {
        public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            return new MyDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }

    public class MyDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }




        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
}
```

### Class library `ApplicationUser.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

}
```

When I try to migrate using: `Add-Migration`

I get this error:

> An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class
>   'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   AddEntityFrameworkStores can only be called with a user that derives
>   from IdentityUser.

When I searched this error I keep getting questions about customising the Identity models, but this is not my case. I'm just trying to migrate it as is. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like your ApplicationUser doesn't inherit from IdentityUser. Can you add the Code of your ApplicationUser?

Comment: @Nikolaus I've added the file. It's just the basic, empty class that is added automatically to the project.

Comment: Can you add the using in your ApplicationUser.cs and your context-file?

Comment: @Nikolaus what do you mean by using? This is just the base which I'm trying to migrate before I use the context in any way.

Comment: I mean the using statements on top of the .cs files, like `using System;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I used `AddIdentity<>` wrong.
Should have used `ApplicationUser` instead of `MyDbContext`.
this is the corrected version:

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```